# Interop Excel C# get Range's Formula with named range inside in A1-Style (Example: C11= Revenue - Benefits --> how to get--> C11= B4-B5)

Tags: c#, excel, interop, range, formula

Everything is in the title,

I would to get a formula of a range in "cell format".

The formula has named range like benefits or profits, so the formula that i get with formula.ToString() is --> = beneftis -profits

but i would like to get the "cell" A1-Style like =C4-C5

Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could get the workbook names, and then replace the names with the addresses in your formula. If _App is your excel instance:

```
Dictionary<string, string> nameDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Name aName in _App.Names)
    nameDict[aName.Name] = ((String)aName.RefersTo).Substring(1); // the address starts with an '='
string fString = formula.ToString();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in nameDict)
    fString = fString.Replace(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
```